# Symbols are not aligned properly with the adjacent features

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have two style layers, one for line and another for symbol. I am trying to align the these features inline but never could so.
[image]

I have given the symbols style layer's layout properties as below.

```
"layout": {
        "text-ignore-placement": true,
        "text-allow-overlap": true,
        "text-pitch-alignment": "map",
        "text-rotate": ["*", -1, ["get", "_Rotation"]],
        "symbol-placement": "point",
        "visibility": "visible",
        "text-anchor": "center",
        "text-field": "A",
        "text-font":["arial"]
      }
```

Tried many things with the properties to get the expected behavior but none are working. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It should work with [line](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-symbol-placement)

```
"layout": {
    "symbol-placement": "line",
    "text-field": 'this is a test',
},
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with this approach is that the symbol is repeated multiple times across the line. I want it to appear only once. somehow, mapbox is repeating the symbol if I specify "symbol-placement" as "line". Any way to stop this?

Comment: What about "symbol-placement": "line-center"?